How to intercept API response of a webRequest in Chrome Extension?
I'm a little new to Chrome Extension Development. The plan is to intercept response of a specific API call. I was able to filter the specific API call using chrome.webRequest API. To be more specific, I am using chrome.webRequest.onCompleted. Now the problem is I am unable to get the api response in the callback function of the event listener. Someone on the github pages suggested to add requestBody in extraInfoSpec. But now I'm getting error, the control never reaches in the callback function. Could you please help me understand what am I missing here?
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
  async (details) => {
    // console.log(details.url)
    if (
      details.url.indexOf('voyager/api/graphql') !== -1 &&
      details.url.indexOf('profileUrn') !== -1
    ) {
      console.log(details)
    }
  },
  {
    urls: ['*://www.example.com/*'], // changed it for the obvious reasons
  },
  ['requestBody']
)

I tried a few things I found on the internet.
Expected: I need the API response in the event listener callback. I don't want to use debugger API, as it shows a warning. And that's not a good UX.
